# How to use Thymeleaf for JavaScript in Spring Boot?

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, thymeleaf

In a Spring Boot application I want to use Thymeleaf to populate a JavaScript file which itself gets preprocessed via `babel` through `WebPack`.

The Thymeleaf configuration looks like this:

```java
@Bean
public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine(MessageSource webTemplateMessageSource) {
    SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
    templateEngine.addTemplateResolver(htmlTemplateResolver());
    templateEngine.addTemplateResolver(javaScriptTemplateResolver());
    templateEngine.setTemplateEngineMessageSource(webTemplateMessageSource);
    templateEngine.setEnableSpringELCompiler(true);
    templateEngine.addDialect(new SpringSecurityDialect());
    return templateEngine;
}

@Bean
public ViewResolver viewResolver(SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine) {
    ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine);
    viewResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    viewResolver.setOrder(1);
    return viewResolver;
}

public SpringResourceTemplateResolver htmlTemplateResolver() {
    SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
    templateResolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
    templateResolver.setPrefix("classpath:templates/web/");
    templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
    templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
    templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    templateResolver.setOrder(0);
    return templateResolver;
}

public SpringResourceTemplateResolver javaScriptTemplateResolver() {
    SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
    templateResolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
    // templateResolver.setPrefix("/js/");
    templateResolver.setSuffix(".js");
    templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.JAVASCRIPT);
    templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    templateResolver.setOrder(1);
    return templateResolver;
}
```

An example HTML page looks like that:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<head>
    <title>Secrets</title>
</head>

<body>

    <button id="secret-button">Tell me the secret</button>

    <script th:src="@{/js/scripts.js}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This page relies on a simple JavaScript file where I want to populate the `secretMessage` variable via ThymeLeaf with a message property:

```js
const secretMessage = [[#{secret}]];
document.querySelector("#secret-button").addEventListener("click", ev => {
    alert(secretMessage);
});
```

The message itself is located in a dedicated message source, just looking like that:

```
secret=Elvis 'still alive
```

And at last here the relevant excerpt of the WebPack config:

```js
let babelConfig = {
    test: /\.js$/i,
    exclude: /(node_modules)/,
    use: {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-react', '@babel/preset-env']
        }
    }
};
```

All together, this setup unfortunately doesn't work, since `babel` moans about the following line of code inside the JavaScript file: `const secretMessage = [[#{secret}]];`.

Also I'm not sure if I'm still missing some further configurations. I couldn't find any examples or information of how to implement Thymeleaf with Spring Boot for parsing JavaScript. Any help would be really appreciated.

#### Edit

For testing purposes I've also tried to get the JavaScript file processed without webpack bundling. For this, the JS file is directly put to the static/build/js folder. Unfortunately, the requested JS file (requested by the HTML page) won't get processed by the Thymeleaf engine anyway.

So besides the preprocessing problem with webpack-bundling there is also a processing problem with Thymeleaf itself. Since I can't find any tutorials about that I'm little bit stuck in a trial-and-error situation without knowing if it's even possible to achieve what I want.

#### Edit 2:

Deleted

#### Edit 3:

According to M. Deinum I added a `ViewController` by overriding `addViewControllers` of the `WebMvcConfigurer` interface:

```java
@Override
public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addViewController("*.js");
}
```

Additionally, since I don't know any better and unfortunately it's still not working, I removed the `templateResolver.setPrefix("/js/");` of the related `javaScriptTemplateResolver` in the hope to not restrict anything in any way. However, currently the JavaScript file still doesn't get processed by Thymeleaf.

Comment: So your problem isn't Thymeleaf but your pre-processing before that. So why should this be a Spring / Thymeleaf issue (as it isn't).

Comment: Unfortuanetely, the current configuration seems to be a Spring Boot/Thymeleaf problem as well (besides the webpack processing problem which I mentioned for the case someone achieved to put a working stack together like I have tried). If I skip webpack bundling (for this forget the babelConfig, the JS file is directly put to the static/build/js folder) the requested JS file (requested by the HTML page) won't get processed by the Thymeleaf engine. Unfortunateley I don't even know whether this is possible or not, but it would seem to be a standard task to me.

Comment: `static` isn't processed by Thymeleaf as that is served directly by the Spring resource support and not Thymeleaf. So don't put it in static but in the thymeleaf paths, next to that you would need a view resolver to handle the `js` files to generate a view name. You can probably use a the viewcontroller configuration (accessible through the `WebMvcConfigurer` to handle that).

Comment: I added your suggestions to the question. Could you maybe give an example of how to config a viewcontroller for this purpose - and is it still required although I added a viewresolver to the Thymeleaf config?

Comment: A viewcontroller is not a viewresolver those things have different roles and ar edifferent things (if you would read/scan the Spring Framework MVC chapter you would know) I also nowhere stated you shold add an additional one. You shouldn't add multiple view resolver for thymeleaf just one. As stated let your configuration implement the `WebMvcConfigurer` interface and override the `addViewController` method and implement it registering to `*.js` to generate a view name.

Comment: I updated the question's code according to @M.Deinum in the hope to got the suggestions this time right. If there is anything else to do please let me know. Thanks

Comment: Your view resolver isn't being added, you stopped after the mapping, you still need to declare what to map it to.

Comment: Thanks @M.Deinum, in my working code I have it added yet as Metroids stated out this issue. I will update it in the question as well. - You mean the template resolver, right? Or do I have to do something with the view resolver as well in addition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your template engine, you need to add both resolvers:

```
templateEngine.addTemplateResolver(htmlTemplateResolver());
templateEngine.addTemplateResolver(javaScriptTemplateResolver());
```

And since you are running it through Thymeleaf, you also need a controller with a mapping for your JavaScript file somewhere:

```
@GetMapping("/js/index.js")
public String indexJs() {
  return "index";
}
```

Comment: Yes man, this is the answer I was looking for! To get it working finally I had to set the prefix of the javaScriptTemplateResolver to `templateResolver.setPrefix("classpath:static/build/js/");` as well, although M. Deinum mentioned to link to the mapped static sources. However, since the mapped static source contains the same files as the resource static folder this doesn't seem to be a problem to me. Also adding a viewController via `WebMvcConfigurer` interface seems not to be sufficient to trigger Thymeleaf processing, but your explicit controller endpoint does.  Thanks again, perfect.

Comment: What also needs to be mentioned is, that I had to set `templateResolver.setCheckExistence(true);` in both template resolvers to make Thymeleaf find related templates.

Comment: Yeah, I thought that was true... but it didn't seem make a difference when I was testing on the latest version of springboot (not sure why), so I left it out.

Comment: I tried to config the template resolvers as recommended without `setCheckExistence(true)` but could not get success as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77031415/how-to-setresolvablepatterns-in-thymeleaf) - therefore my additional explanation for seekers who might just copy 'n paste the question's code and apply your solution. This way everyone gets happy :)

Comment: The view resolver does exactly the same as the aformentioned dedicated request handling method so should work as well (and easier). Your view resolver adding was just wrong as it didn't add a view resolver, you stopped after the mapping hence it didn't register anything.

Comment: @M.Deinum I'm a little confused now, I thought Spring Boot will find my View Resolver automatically and register it to use it for its purpose. I have never seen in any example that I have to do something further with the view resolver. Can you point me to an example so that I can get things right?

Comment: The view resolver needed to be view controller in my comment (lack of coffee).

Comment: Tell me about coffee ;). So I still need to declare what to map the ViewController to? I just tried to goole for some examples but couldn't find anything. The `ViewControllerRegistry` doesn't have any methods to do this. And as simple it might be if you know what to do, I'm unfortunately at a point not only facing lack of coffee but also lack of knowledge. Any help or hint would really be appreciated.