# How to set up Thymeleaf Template Engine for JavaScript in Spring Boot?

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Thymeleaf seems to be the standard template engine for Spring Boot applications. There are plenty of tutorials to find of how to set up Thymeleaf for HTML pages. Unfortunately I can't find a single one which explains how to set up  Thymeleaf properly for JavaScript files requested by HTML pages.

Since this imo should be a bread and butter task I'm a bit surprised that I can't find any examples about that.

I don't want to go too much into code because I've [already tried here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77024439/how-to-use-thymeleaf-for-javascript-in-spring-boot), so I just want to give a simple starting base asking for any further hints:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head></head>

<body>
    <script th:src="@{/js/scripts.js}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

All I want to do is preprocessing the `/js/scripts.js` via Thymeleaf at the time when the HTML page requests this JS file.

**My question therefore is:**

How can I implement Thymeleaf into Spring Boot to get Thymeleaf processed a JavaScript file requested by an HTML page?

Comment: Thymeleaf doesn't execute javascript. It only executes html and inline backend code. Could you clarify what you mean by "preprocessing" the javascript using Thymeleaf? Maybe an example of a specific task...

Comment: Hi @UsmanMutawakil, I thought since one can set up a `TemplateResolver` for `TemplateMode.JAVASCRIPT` Thymeleaf can also process JavaScript files. What I want to achieve is to deliver JS files which get preprocessed by the Thymeleaf engine, so that I can populate variables inside the JS files with values from the application context. I know that I can set up explicit endpoints to do this, but I want to generalize all requested JS files to run through the Thymeleaf engine. This should be something like a standard task for monoliths, at least I thought so.

Comment: I see what you mean now. Disregard my previous comment. I thought you were trying to run the actual Javascript on the backend.

Comment: ^^, would pe possible with Node, but no, I just want to use preprocessed JS files. Inlining would work, but then I would have to put required variables into global scope to get access from the JS files. Also, this work around looks kind of messy with scattered pieces of eventually related code. I'd rather put the variables right to the place where they should be in the beginning.

Comment: Any chance you can solve this by putting the preprocessing in your build? For example have gradle or one of its plugins manipulate your js for you? Kinda like how you would use grunt with node...

Comment: @UsmanMutawakil Processing the template has to be per request, since the variables get populated relating on specific authenticated users or browser settings. However, many thanks for your interest. Fortunately this problem got [solved by Metroids in this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77024439/how-to-use-thymeleaf-for-javascript-in-spring-boot). It's kind of the same problem but questioned in a much more specific way. Anyhow, I will leave this question alive for the case, someone comes up with a better state of the art solution for a pretty standard task.