# How to setResolvablePatterns() in Thymeleaf?

Tags: thymeleaf

According to [Thymeleaf's documentation](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.1/usingthymeleaf.html#chaining-template-resolvers) it is recommended to set resolvable patterns for different template resolvers.

I have two template resolvers, one for `HTML` and one for `JavaScript`. The following code shows the setup of these two resolvers and as you can see, I try to use `setResolvablePatterns()` instead of `setCheckExistence(true)`.

```java
public SpringResourceTemplateResolver htmlTemplateResolver() {
    SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
    templateResolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
    templateResolver.setPrefix("classpath:templates/web/");
    templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
    templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
    templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    templateResolver.setOrder(0);

    templateResolver.setResolvablePatterns(Collections.singleton("/*.html"));
    // templateResolver.getResolvablePatternSpec().addPattern("/*.html"); // doesn't work either

    // templateResolver.setCheckExistence(true);
    return templateResolver;
}

public SpringResourceTemplateResolver javaScriptTemplateResolver() {
    SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
    templateResolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
    templateResolver.setPrefix("classpath:static/build/js/");
    templateResolver.setSuffix(".js");
    templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.JAVASCRIPT);
    templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    templateResolver.setOrder(1);

    templateResolver.setResolvablePatterns(Collections.singleton("/*.js"));
    // templateResolver.setResolvablePatterns(Collections.singleton("*.js")); // doesn't work either
    // templateResolver.setResolvablePatterns(Collections.singleton("*"));    // doesn't work either

    // templateResolver.setCheckExistence(true);
    return templateResolver;
}
```

Unfortunately, when using this recommended configuration, all I get are errors that the templates might not exist:

```
o.t.TemplateEngine : [THYMELEAF] Exception processing template "users/login": Error resolving template [users/login], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
 org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template [users/login], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
```

Using `templateResolver.setCheckExistence(true)` instead works as expected. Does anybody know what I am missing here?

Comment: I'm guessing your controller should be returning `users/login.html` instead of `users/login` in this case... since I think it's attempting to match based on the view and since `users/login` doesn't match `*.html` it doesn't find anything.

Comment: Yes, you are right, as soon as I return not only the template names alone but template names with suffix it works. But is this really the way to go, since I then not only have to return all templates explicitly by their full name (e.g. index.html) but also have to rename all layout replacements (e.g th:replace="~{_layout/_includes/_footer.html :: footer}"). Since I have never read anything that quirksy about in documentations, I hope there is a better solution.

Comment: Maybe providing prefix and suffix alone in the template resolver is sufficient for performance? No template request should hit the resolver which is not configured for it. So maybe we can omit `templateResolver.setResolvablePatterns()` and rely on prefix and suffix alone? Or maybe there is something like a wildcard which will work, however `/*` or `*` doesn't do the trick ;)

Comment: You could put the javascript resolver as order 0 instead and use resolveable patterns there and then leave the html resolver with it's more default settings (no resolveable pattern, setCheckExistence = false).  Then you only have to specify the full name for your javascript files.

Comment: @Metroids Great advice, many thanks for these insights. I'm getting smarter day by day, no telling where i'll be a year from now ;)